# Every subset of a finite set is finite

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there anyway I can prove this statement using the pigeonhole principle below?

"If A,B are sets and B is finite, and there is an injection $f : A \rightarrow B$, then A is finite and $Card(A)\leq Card(B)$"

I have seen the way that uses induction but I wonder if there is any other ways to do it.

Comment: The statement in your title is different from the statement in the problem. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: Or are you assuming $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: Oh I am sorry for making confusion. I am asking about the one in title

Answer (score 2):

It seems the quoted result immediately implies what you want to show: Let $F$ be a finite set and $A \subseteq F.$ Then the inclusion map $I:A\to F$ defined by $f(a)=a$ for $a \in A$ is an injective map from $A$ into $F.$ So by the quoted result $A$ is finite.

Comment: Is the inclusion map always injective?

Comment: @Meer Yes, since for all $a$ in $A,$ $f(a)=a$ we have: $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ using $f(x)=x,\ f(y)=y.$